# SQL GROUP_CONCAT not working with 2 table join

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

I have this query which is working as expected:

**Query**

```
SELECT name, date, enddate, abo_name, bill_id
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(c.firstname, " ", c.surname) AS name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.date) AS date, GROUP_CONCAT(b.endDate) AS enddate, GROUP_CONCAT(b.abo_id) AS abo_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS bill_id
    FROM customer c
    LEFT JOIN bill b ON c.id = b.customer_id
    GROUP BY name
) t
```

**Output (JSON)**

```
{
    name: "Max Mustermann",
    date: "2018-09-13,2018-09-27",
    enddate: "2018-09-13,2018-09-28",
    abo_name: "1,2",
    bill_id: "23,27"
},
...
```

But now I need to add more detailed information to the abo_name property, I need  to output the full abo name. I tried to just add an `INNER JOIN` to the query, but then the `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't work anymore.

Here's the example:

**Query**

```
SELECT name, date, enddate, abo_name, bill_id
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(c.firstname, " ", c.surname) AS name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.date) AS date, GROUP_CONCAT(b.endDate) AS enddate, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) AS abo_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS bill_id
    FROM customer c
    LEFT JOIN bill b ON c.id = b.customer_id
    INNER JOIN abo a ON b.abo_id = a.id
    GROUP BY name
) t
```

**Output (JSON)**

```
{
    name: "Max Mustermann",
    date: "2018-09-13",
    enddate: "2018-09-13",
    abo_name: "Einzelstunde",
    bill_id: "23"
},
{
    name: "Max Mustermann",
    date: "2018-09-27",
    enddate: "2018-09-28",
    abo_name: "Schnupperstunde",
    bill_id: "27"
},
```

As you can see the data doesn't concat and 2 objects are created. Does anybody have an idea why this is the case?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Either the names are different (hidden characters) or you might have a column named `name` in one of the tables.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because even if I don't change anything in the SELECT part and just add the JOIN, it doesn't get concated.

Comment: . . Does `abo` have a column called `name`?

Comment: Yes, `abo` has a column called `name`

Comment: There's no need to wrap the query in a subquery. The outer query is selecting all the columns from the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abo` has a column named name.  Aggregate by the expression or use a different alias:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.surname) AS new_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.date) AS date, GROUP_CONCAT(b.endDate) AS enddate, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) AS abo_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.id) AS bill_id
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     bill b
     ON c.id = b.customer_id INNER JOIN
     abo a
     ON b.abo_id = a.id
GROUP BY new_name
```